# Train using images instead of tfrecords?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, ram, custom-object

I am working with a huge dataset and RAM is my limitation as it gets full during creation of tfrecords. Is it possible to do tensorflow training using images and labels directly instead of first creating and then using tfrecords?